# background positioning mismatch css

Tags: html, css

So, I tried to apply a sticky background to a div which worked. The problem I have now is that it doesn't stretch sufficiently during scroll. This is the CSS I used to apply the background. Here I have some screenshots showing the error.

[image: aligned nicely]

after scroll:

[image: not aligned]

```
.site-main {
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background: url("http://areca3000.nl/glissenaar/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/bg-content.jpg")
 no-repeat  center center fixed ;
    /* background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-size: 100%;    
    padding: 0 0 0 0 !important;
    /*max-width: 1220px !important; 8? */ 
 }
```

The url of the page is http://www.areca3000.nl/glissenaar/ if you want to check it out.

Comment: I have read the question four times but I still can't work out what you want to achieve. It doesn't stretch suffucuently is all your giving us?

Comment: @Obsidian The problem I have is that the background doesn't fill the div while scrolling. Thanks for the effort though

Answer (score 1):

If you want the background to fit its container both vertically and horizontally then you need to change your `background-size` rule to

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

*Note that this technique will distort your image and it may not look as you want*